# GA4 not tracking events fired by GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

**I have a tag, with the event name 'generate_lead'. GTM says it's successfully firing to my GA4 property (ending 988)**

[image: I have a tag, with the event name 'generate_lead'. GTM says it's successfully firing to my GA4 property (ending 988)]

**However, GA4 says that it has never been fired, both in the report, and in the real time monitoring.**

[image: However, GA4 says that it has never been fired, both in the report, and in the real time monitoring.]

**I have created a custom event with the same name**

[image: I have created a custom event with the same name]

**As well as a conversion event with the same name**

[image: As well as a conversion event with the same name]

**But still, nothing. This feels like such a downgrade from UA. Surely I must be doing something wrong, but I can't spot what it is.**

Comment: how long since you fired the event and looking up data in GA4. Sometimes it can take up to a day for data to start appearing. If you want more real time insights you should have a look at the big query export. (the intraday table). Btw the custom event functionality is to create events based on current events (you don't need it).So if you event tag is configured properly the data should start flowing in.

Comment: Well, it's been a week now, and It's still not showing as having ever been fired in the last 90 days despite extensive testing.

Comment: Can you doublecheck your tag configuration. Is it pointing to the right streamid? You can also check your collect events in the network tab. Is it appearing there and does it have a statuscode of 200? I would also remove the custom event (second screenshot) it might be  that it goes wrong there since it has the same name (it's not needed).